# Geometry-Teory of parallels

Tags: geometry

Can anyone suggest me a book about the history of the theory of parallels,  something about attempts to prove the fifth postulate?

Comment: I think William Dunham's Journey Through Genius: The Great Theorems of Mathematics, pages 53 to 60, is good. The link is: http://kheavan.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/william-dunham-journey-through-genius-the-great-theorems-of-mathematics-penguin-non-classics1991014014739x.pdf